# How to check if a state variable of type address is not initialized?

Tags: solidity, addresses

In contract B I need to provide a contract address before I can call functions logUint and logString. How do I check in these functions that **A logger** is not empty? `if(!logger)` and `if(!address(logger))` doesn't compile.

```
contract A {
    function logUint(uint a);
    function logString(string a);
}

contract B {
    A logger;
    function registerLogger(address loggerAddress){
        logger = A(loggerAddress);
    }       
    function logUint(uint a){
        //if(/*what do I put here*/)
        logger.logUint(a);
    }
    function logString(string a){
        //if(/*what do I put here*/)
        logger.logString(a);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `address(contractInstance) != address(0)`

Example:

```
function logUint(uint a){
    if (address(logger) != address(0)) {
        logger.logUint(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone will suggest something cleaner but I normally do:

```
address NULL_ADDRESS;
if (logger == NULL_ADDRESS) { whatever; }
```

Comment: This typically works but it only checks if the first 20 bytes of the contract instance are 0x0. I'm not sure there can be contracts that have the first 20-bytes zeros and other functional code afterwards.

Comment: Nice catch - sorry, I misread the original post and assumed he was checking for an empty address.

Comment: Not following why this answer was deleted, nor the first comment.

Comment: @eth I deleted my answer because I realised I misunderstood the question. However looking again I think my answer matches the title, it's the posted code that doesn't match...

Comment: I thought you deleted because of @Sebi's comment: what does it mean and why upvoted?

Comment: @eth Addresses are 20 bytes long. The code works only if the first 20 bytes of the contract are zeros but like I stated I'm not sure if we can have contracts that have the first 20 bytes 0s and the remainder non-zero values which would make the check erroneous.

Comment: @Sebi, yes addresses are only 20 bytes, but that doesn't apply to this answer because `logger` will be [implicitly converted](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#implicit-conversions) to an `address`.  The code of `logger` isn't a factor.  Also: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#get-contract-address-in-solidity

Comment: But how is the conversion made? Aren't only the first 20 bytes taken from the `logger` instance and the rest (if the `logger` is more than 20 bytes long) discarded?

Comment: @Sebi: That could be a good new question; I'm not sure currently how to explain better than the FAQ I linked.